# How works the NS record definition in DNS section at CloudFlare?

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

In domain configuration at CloudFlare, the DNS section stores the record definitions. What is the exact purpose of NS record here? If configured, it shows something like:

```
Type | Name       | Value                     | TTL
-----+------------+---------------------------+----------
NS   | domain.com | managed by ns1.domain.com | Automatic
```

But the NS at authoritative DNS server (registrar) is configured accordingly to the CloudFlare assignments:

```
adi.ns.cloudflare.com
bob.ns.cloudflare.com
```

And the latter are presented if the domain is queried for example by any DNS propagation checker (e.g. whatsmydns.net).

The domain is being *managed by* their DNS anyway, so what's the purpose of defining the NS records in CloudFlare configuration panel?

Comment: This question really isn't specific to Cloudflare, so I'm going to link this to the existing Q&A. Let me know if you still have questions after reading it.

Comment: @AndrewB After performing some tests I must admit that is simpler as expected and exactly as You suggested - just a delegation of authority for a subdomain to another NS. What caused the confusion was the idea of CloudFlare, however the NS record functionality is a must anyway.

Comment: Actually, apex NS records are not used for delegation. If the apex NS records don't match what is defined at the registrar, that's a phenomenon known as a *glue record mismatch*. (sometimes queries hit the servers defined at the registrar, and sometimes they hit the ones defined in your zone file) It's very confusing to try and understand how that works, so stick with this simplified advice: *The NS records defined in your registrar account are temporary hints on how to find your zone file. They should always match the NS records at the top of your zone file, or unexpected things will happen.*